# How to reference in XAML a dependent property in another assembly which is based on enum in 3rd assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I have a WPF window in assembly A, which is referencing a dependent property in Assembly B.  This dependent property value is a enum that is located in assembly C.

If I by chance make the dependent property's value enum in assembly B I can reference the values just fine, but when I try to move it to another assembly for design purposes I run afoul with a XAML error "The member 'ConnectionMode' is not recognized or is not accessible."

Enum (in assembly C):

```
public enum ConnectionMode { Slanted, Square }
```

Property (in assembly B):

```
    private static readonly DependencyProperty ConnectionModeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ConnectionMode",
        typeof(TreeConnectionMode),
        typeof(TreeContainerProperties),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            TreeConnectionMode.SlantedLines,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
    public static void SetConnectionMode(TreeContainer target, TreeConnectionMode value) => target.SetValue(ConnectionModeProperty, value);
    public static TreeConnectionMode GetCheckedBackground(TreeContainer target) => (TreeConnectionMode)target.GetValue(ConnectionModeProperty);
```

XAML Reference in control:

```
 TreeContainer:TreeContainerProperties.ConnectionMode="SlantedLines"
```

Answer (score -1):

I was under the mistaken belief that there was a code issue that I had.  But the problem was associated with the XDG0012 error VisualStudio was giving me.  It appears if you change the CPU from Any to any specific value, it will resolve.